# Column autofit width

Tags: c#, xml, openoffice-calc, ods

I am creating an OpenDocument spreadsheet .ods in C# by constructing the XML "table" element manually. (The OpenOffice API seems to be very limited and is thereby not really an option).

**Question is:** Is it possibly to set a property (i.e. `XML attribute`) which will auto-fit a column depending on the content?

The only way I currently see is to use the API anyway after constructing the document and set the `XPropertySet "OptimalWidth"`. I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the xml that results after using the api to set the `XPropertySet "OptimalWidth"` property?

Comment: Yes I did that already. What acutally seems to happen when you set this property is that the OpenOffice function is called which determines the optimal width based on the current content of a column (as if you would double click on the column border in Calc (or Excel) ). So after that the width is fixed in the XML (e.g. "3.45cm")